# Nodejs + Rickshaw: src= reference not working

Tags: html, node.js, express, d3.js, rickshaw

I am trying to make an app the generates 'live' graphs of Twitter word counts, basically trying to extend and exercise in Chapter 14 of NodeJS in 24 Hours.  I decided to use 'Rickshaw' and I thought I'd start with simply getting a simple example working.  However, while I can get a simple html page to load, I can't get a graph to display.  Firefox debug indicates: "ReferenceError: Rickshaw is not defined [Break On This Error] graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( { " .  That means that there is a referencing error but after a couple of hours of googling and reading, I'm not seeing it.  The directory structure is correct; npm installed all modules correctly, no errors.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Note: I am new to JS/Node and while the book is working in Express 2.x, I have been working in Express 3.x, so not sure if I've got the translation correct in all cases.  The code is as follows:

package.json

```
    {
    "name":"socket.io-twitter-example",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": "true",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": ">=2.5.4",
        "rickshaw": ">=1.1.0"
        }
    }
```

app.js

```
    var express = require('express'),
        rickshaw = require('rickshaw'),
        app = express(),
        http = require('http'),
        server = http.createServer(app)

    server.listen(3000);
    app.get('/', function (req,res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="eng">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>Socket.IO Twitter Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Rickshaw Example</h1>


            <div id="chart"></div>
            <ul class="tweets"></ul>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/rickshaw/vendor/d3.v2.js"></script> //don't think "node_modules/" is required, but doesn't work without either
            <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.js"></script>

            <script>
                graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
                    element: document.querySelector("#chart"), 
                    width: 285, 
                    height: 180, 
                    series: [{
                        color: 'steelblue',
                        data: [ 
                            { x: 0, y: 40 }, 
                            { x: 1, y: 49 }, 
                            { x: 2, y: 38 }, 
                            { x: 3, y: 30 }, 
                            { x: 4, y: 32 } ]
                    }]
                });
                graph.render();
            </script> 


        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure `express.static` middleware so that `express` knows where to look for static resources like js and css files:

```
app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/public'));
```

Its common to put such resources into a `public` folder (as shown in the example above) or `static` folder.

If you create a `public` folder and organize it like

```
app.js
public
  rickshaw
    vendor
      d3.v2.js
    rickshaw.min.js
```

then you'll be able to have the files correctly loaded in your html using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/rickshaw/vendor/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.js"></script>
```

See [this section](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) of the `express` docs for more info on and examples of middleware.